# LinQ returning no datarow error

Tags: c#, linq

In below code, *Hours* is passed with selected values from the UI as below

`Hours = "10.1, 11.2";`

If there is no value from UI, these will contain as below.

`Hours = "";`

Below code is to slipt them & get the value from Database. This gives error if the values are having "".

Error at `q.CopyToDataTable()` **The source contains no DataRows.**

```
public void Populate_Gridview(string Hours)
{

string[] selectedHours = Hours.Split(',');

var q = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where selectedHours.Contains(a.Field<double?>("Hours").ToString()) 
    select a;

GridView1.DataSource = q.CopyToDataTable();
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

If I have Double array, I cannot slipt them if the input is not having any value i.e. "". I get error **Input string was not in a correct format.**

```
Double[] selectedHours = Array.ConvertAll(All.Split(','), Double.Parse);
```

Please guide on how I can solve this issue.

Comment: try using q.Any() and then only bind DataSource

Comment: Database has the value. It should be like if the UI is passing nothing i.e. "" then all values of Hours has to be retrieved and bind to GridView. It is as good as removing the where clause. But I cannot remove this clause due to design contraints

Comment: you can then have or condition in where clause as selectedHours.Length==0

Comment: @Nitin, that worked for me.. I had to use OR condition with selectedHours[0] == "". Can you post this as an answer please.. Thanks much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var q = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where (selectedHours.Contains(a.Field<double?>("Hours").ToString()) 
    || selectedHours.Length==0)
    select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `CopyToDataTable` only works if the source has some rows in it. Otherwise, it cannot determine the columns to be included in the table. A possible solution is to create an empty destination table with the right columns, and copy the rows to that table:

```
var destTable = dt.Copy();
destTable.Rows.Clear();
q.CopyToDataTable(destTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
GridView1.DataSource = destTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The other issue is that, when called on an empty string, by default `Split` returns an array with on empty string, hence the error when you call `Double.Parse` on it. To avoid this, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] splitted = All.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Double[] selectedHours = Array.ConvertAll(splitted, Double.Parse);
```

Comment: Thanks much Thomas for the suggestion. This helped me for my learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

First, i would improve the way you are deriving the doubles from the string since your way is error prone and inefficient. You could try this approach:

```
double[] selectedHours = hours.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(str => {
        str = str.Trim();
        double hour;
        bool isDouble = double.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out hour);
        return new { str, isDouble, hour };
    })
    .Where(h => h.isDouble)
    .Select(h => h.hour)
    .ToArray();

var q = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        join hour in selectedHours
        on row.Field<double?>("Hours") equals hour 
        select row;
var dataSource = dt.Clone(); // empty
if (q.Any())
    dataSource = q.CopyToDataTable();
```